# Do C++ compilers perform tricks to make moving data within classes faster?

Tags: c++

I'm curious about the optimisations that C++ compilers do when it comes to moving data around during run-time. Recently, I've been thinking about how classes are passed through the code as I know that if you pass a `bool` to a function you don't need to define it as `const&` but if you have, for example, a `std::vector<T>` then typically you would use `const&` as this tends to be larger than 64 bits and thus is more efficient to do so.

Now, if you had a `class` which consists of two variables, a `uint8_t` and a `int8_t`, would the compiler, under the covers, move this class around as it would a single `int16_t` or `uint16_t`? Similarly, with a class with two `int32_t` would it be treated in the same manner when moving around in memory as a single `int64_t`?

Comment: Maybe.  Maybe not.  The compiler's *as if* rule gives it a lot of leeway.

Comment: Define "move around". Are you refering to the use of the implicitly declared default constructor + copy assignment operator used when passing this kind of data structure by value?

Comment: Say you pass the class to a function as an input parameter, and if it contains two 8 bit integers, would it be treated like one 16 bit integer?

Rather than focusing on the actual specifics of the move semantics I'm more curious on if the compiler tries to optimise things. Like if passing a class would it try to move it as one "entity" ?

Comment: ABI vs the _as-if-rule_ - you will need to look at the generated optimised assembly and/or read the Itanium C++ ABI spec https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html . _The as-if rule_ - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the compiler will, by default, copy an `int64_t` and a class or struct containing two `int_32_t` **the same way**. Both cases are simply 8 bytes of raw memory on mainstream architectures, so at the low level of copying data they will be treated as such. (For classes and structs this behavior can be changed by overriding the copy/move constructor/assignment operator.)

Copies are done *as-if* the bytes of memory are copied one-by-one from location to another. One optimization the compiler might do is store the values in a [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) instead of main memory if the memory address of the value is not used. The fact that the bytes of memory might represent a class or struct don't prevent the compiler from making that optimization.

A standards-compliant compiler could be written that would treat `int64_t` and a struct of 2 `int_32_t` differently, but in practice it doesn't make sense to do so.